# Custom Action Fails

Tags: vb.net

I have a custom action to run a batch file after installation. It works fine in windows 7 but doesnt in XP.

Here is the code I have used to run the batch file

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Configuration.Install
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Environment
<Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)>
Public Class StartBatch
    Public Function appData() As String
        appData = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
    End Function
<Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)> _
    Public Overrides Sub Commit(ByVal savedState As  _
  System.Collections.IDictionary)

        MyBase.Commit(savedState)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(appData() & "\Wilson18\IPChanger\IPFinder.bat")
    End Sub

End Class
```

How would I either be able to get this to work on windows XP or, if the action fails then it doesnt interup the installer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is because of this

```
<Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)> _
    Public Overrides Sub Commit(ByVal savedState As  _
  System.Collections.IDictionary)
```

We are demanding security from installer and it might ask you to start with Administrator however in Winxp there is no such option; probably give it a try to run as administrator.